# How can I create a Spring Entity that has an object of the same type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The project can be found here: github.com/jareid/SRTTranslator

I am trying to add the REST API methods for a simple Spring application

My SubtitleContents class contains a nextSubtitleContents and previousSubtitleContents which are both SubtitleContents objects. THe file can be found here: https://github.com/jareid/SRTTranslator/blob/main/src/main/java/com/jreid/srttranslator/entities/SubtitleContents.java

This results in the following error when running the application

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.jreid.srttranslator.entities.SubtitleContents`
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at com.jreid.srttranslator.SrttranslatorApplication.main(SrttranslatorApplication.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Too many Id annotations. Should be only one per entity class.

Comment: Thank you, that was a mistake, I meant to add a NotNull annotation but this doesnt fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SubtitleContents` as a column in another entity class `Subtitle` without a proper annotation. Probably you meant `@OneToOne` but it is not (yet) there. Hibernate doesn't know what to do with it. The same problem with columns `previousSubtitleContents` and `nextSubtitleContents`.

Comment: Pushed your change but the error hasn't changed